# Is it possible to create a like button with no AJAX?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm building my first rails app and want to implement a like button to like posts. Most of the resources I can find on how to do this involve using AJAX. I was wondering if there is a way to implement a like button without using AJAX?

Comment: What do you want  to do with your Like button?

Comment: simply indicate that the post as been liked and increment the number of likes the post has

Comment: If a user wants to like your post. how will you implement that without AJAX?

Comment: My question is asking if that's even possible to do

Comment: We cant implement without AJAX.

Comment: @HarryB. sure, you can do it without `ajax`, but with reloading the page.

Comment: that's okay with me. I'm definitely cool with a redirect_to as long as I am able to get the like functionality. I just wanted to make sure that it was possible in some way before I tried to start building it

Comment: you could have a custom action in your controller that updates/increments a like counter for your object(whatever is being liked).  The user could trigger the action by clicking on a link_to in your view, which has a custom route that calls upon your custom controller action, which redirects to the same view but with an updated count for likes.  something like that...

Answer (score 6):

Here is the solution: **It will reload your page**

1. Let's say currently you are on your `posts/index.html.erb` page, where all `posts` are showing and also in every post there is a **like** button.
2. Create a new controller named `LikeController.rb`, which will create/remove likes for the post. In your routes make it a nested resource, like: It'll better identify which post got the like button hit.

   `resources :posts do
      resources :likes
   end`
3. Create two methods `create` and `delete` in the newly created controller.
4. In your posts `like` button create a link for the `create` method passing the `post_id`.
5. In the `create` method create the a new `Like` for that post. Post can be find from the `params[:post_id]` which you've passed in the like link.
6. After successful creation of the new `Like` redirect to `back`

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Faye websockets to send a like request to a JavaScript file and update that like count dynamically. Watch a rails cast Podcast for Faye websockets and try to implement a send request from your view. I am sure it will do the job you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without Ajax (although I'm not sure why you'd impose this constraint).

Have an invisible iframe on the page and have your like button submit a form whose target is that iframe. Submitting the form (i.e. Clicking your button) now reloads the frame rather than the whole page. Content in the frame can communicate with the host page (either call methods directly on `window.parent` or use `postMessage`) so you can update a counters on the page and similar.